# jQuery noConflict for a dummy

Tags: javascript, fancybox, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin conflict in Wordpress which I need some help with. On my test page at: http://timbaggaley.co.uk/test/ I have installed the Easy Fancybox plugin for image and video presentation. It worked fine until I installed the jQuery backstretch plugin using code posted into a Javascript adder widget. I'm guessing my problem is the call on multiple libraries and I need to use noConflict. I have amended my code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timbaggaley.co.uk/js-includes/jq_backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = $.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j.backstretch("http://timbaggaley.co.uk/backstretch/pic4.jpg", {speed: 150});});
</script>
```

The backstretch still works but the Fancybox still does not. I am a complete programming novice and I have read as much of the jQery noConflict advice as I can find but cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me with some copy 'n' paste idiot-proof guidance on how to implement the noconflict trick into my website?

Thanks
Tim, London

Comment: did u try $j(this).backstretch?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included two times? `http://timbaggaley.co.uk/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4` and `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

First remove "var $j = $.noConflict();" and Try using "jQuery" instead of "$j"

Comment: `jQuery` remains set after the `noConflict` call (unless you call it with an extra `true` parameter), there is no point in assigning it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, Easy Fancybox uses jQuery, so this is not an issue of using multiple libraries. Therefore you should *not* use `.noConflict()`.

Comment: Yes, but if no other library is actually there, noConflict mode should not be used anyway. The problem here is that the OP is incorrectly guessing that this is a *library* conflict. Afaics, this is a *plugin* conflict.

Answer (score -1):

I would normally just called `$.noConflict()` rather than store it in a variable.
Also, you can avoid conflict all together (normally) by using jQuery(document).ready() instead of $.

Comment: -1: Sorry, but that not true. Asigning another variable is one way to do it, see the examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Yes, I have read through this stuff but I just don't understand it. The code I started with is:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timbaggaley.co.uk/js-includes/jq_backstretch/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.timbaggaley.co.uk/js-includes/jq_backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.backstretch("http://timbaggaley.co.uk/backstretch/pic4.jpg", {speed: 150});
</script>

It works but Easy Fancybox breaks, I take my backstretch code out and EF works - what do I do to get them working together?